# $ select dynamic class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

SOLVED WITH

```
$('.<?php echo 'render-warp-'.$page->getIdPage(); ?>').formRender({
                                        formData: JSON.parse(text),
                                        dataType: 'json'
                                    });
```

I have a problem when i want to select a dynamic class and render something. my div class get the id_page like this :

> class="render-wrap-getIdPage());

So in html i get :

> class="render-wrap-6"

Now in my script i need to select the class in order to user my render method. but actualy when i do something like this it doesn't work.

```
$("#render-warp-" + id).formRender({
                                            formData: JSON.parse(text),
                                            dataType: 'json'
                                        });
```

When i check the inspector i get :

$('.render-warp-' + id).formRender

Anyone know how i could get the id in the selection ?

here the full loop :

```
 <?php foreach ($pages as $page) :?>


                                <div id="<?php echo $page->getIdPage(); ?>" class="render-warp-<?php echo ($page->getIdPage()); ?>"></div>
                                <script>
                                    jQuery(function($) {
                                        var data = <?php echo (json_encode($page->getValeur())); ?>;

                                        var id = <?php echo ($page->getIdPage()); ?>;
                                        var text = data.replace(/&quot;/g, '"');
                                        text = text.replace('"\\"[', '[');
                                        text = text.replace(']\\""', ']');

                                        $('render-warp-' + id).formRender({
                                            formData: JSON.parse(text),
                                            dataType: 'json'
                                        });
                                    });
                                </script>
                            </div>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in your jQuery selector. 
`$('render-warp-' + id)`
should be
`$('#render-wrap-' + id)`

You should probably also fire this on `$(document).ready()` in case your selector doesn't exist in the DOM yet.

Comment: thanks for your reply i edited with $('#render-wrap-' + id) but it's not working it's display me : $('#render-warp-' + id) and not $('#render-warp-6'). how could i use $(document).ready()

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using `'render-wrap'` in your markup, and then `'render-warp'` in your jQuery code.

Comment: sorry my fault i had a mistake when i copied / paste the code